# REST API Authentication from Postman vs Web App

Tags: authentication, tableau-api

I am trying to perform some actions on the Tableau server via REST API for which I require the Auth token. I tried using the signin API from Postman and it works like a charm. However the same code is giving "Bad Request" error whe tried calling from javacript code from my webpage.

```
var dataVal = {
    "credentials": {
        "name": "admin",
        "password": "admin",
        "site": {
            "contentUrl": "MySite"
        }
    }
};

$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataVal),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("call succeeded");
    },
    error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders());
    },
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://mytableauserver/api/2.6/auth/signin'
});
```

The above code return token, siteid, userid from postman but return ""BAD REQUEST" error from javascript code. Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the JS API with Trusted Tickets or the plain JS API?

Comment: Plain JS API. Seems like my requests are getting blocked due to Cross Domain calls. Postman works without issues.

Comment: Did you add the cross origin headers on the server?

Comment: Had a case open with Tableau and their response was

"CORS is usually not allowed due to security reason and Tableau Server will not accept CORS.
To resolve the issue, we recommend you to use server-side scripting such as Python for REST API." Using server side code is not a possibility for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking, Tableau now supports CORS but only on `Tableau Server` at this point.

```
Enabling CORS on Tableau Server for the REST API
For security, most web browsers restrict HTTP requests to the same origin. That is, to 
access a resource on a server through an API, the request must come from the same 
origin (server), or a proxy must be set up to handle the request.

Tableau Server now supports Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), so you can do away 
with your proxy and call the REST API from the browser. The CORS mechanism is 
currently only enabled for Tableau Server, and can be turned on by server 
administrators in a couple of steps using the TSM command-line tool. To learn more, 
see the description of the vizportal.rest_api.cors.allow_origin option in tsm 
configuration set Options. As a security measure, you should make API calls to Tableau 
Server using the HTTPS protocol (SSL or TLS). See Using HTTPS (SSL/TLS) for API Calls.

Add the origins that need access to the Tableau Server.

Determine the origins (servers) you want to allow access to the REST API, and use the 
tsm configuration set command with the vizportal.rest_api.cors.allow_origin option. 
For example, to grant access to one two origins, https://mysite and https://yoursite, 
you would stop the server (tsm stop) and then use the following command:

tsm configuration set -k vizportal.rest_api.cors.allow_origin -v 
https://mysite,https://yoursite
You can enter multiple origins. Use a comma to separate the entries.

Note: You could also use an asterisk (*) as a wild card to match all sites. This is 
not recommended as it allows access from any origin that has access to the server and 
could present a security risk. Do not use an asterisk (*) unless you fully understand 
the implications and risks for your site.

Enable CORS on Tableau Server.

Use the tsm configuration set command with the vizportal.rest_api.cors.enabled option. 
The default setting is false, so set this to true as follows:

tsm configuration set -k vizportal.rest_api.cors.enabled -v true
Update your Tableau Server configuration (tsm pending-changes apply)  to restart 
Tableau Server and make the changes take effect.  Only the origins you specify will 
have access.
```

https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_concepts_fundamentals.htm